# On Integer Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence $1,2,3,...$ can be generated from the polynomial $p(n)=n, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$

However, the sequence $1,2,4,8,...$ can not be generated so.

How can I know if an infinite sequence of non-negative integers can be generated by a polynomial or not?

Comment: For a sequence generated by a (non-zero) polynomial, the limit of the ratio of successive terms is $1$

Comment: @ J, W. Tanner: I am looking for a sufficient condition.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner:  I believe that is necessary but not sufficient.  I could perturb the $p(n)=n$ sequence by $\pm 1$ for each term.  The limit of the ratio is still $1$, but one cannot express the sequence this way.

Comment: @ Ross Millikan: That was a nice observation. Can you think of a sufficient condition for this?

Comment: The standard approach is to take the differences, then the differences of those, and so on.  If the sequence can be represented by a polynomial, the differences will be constant at some stage and zero at all stages after that.  The degree of the polynomial is the number of differences you need to take to get the constant.  It doesn't seem like this is what you are looking for but maybe it is.